# Чтение файла .xsb в Python

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли открыть файл с расширением xsb в Python?
Файл сгенерирован в "Справки БК" (2.5.1) - программе для составления справок госслужащих в налоговую.

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь. Вообще есть такой формат, но он похоже не имеет отношения, у них какой-то самодельный.

Answer (score 1):

Как правило государственные структуры обмениваются XML файлами. И сам .XSB формат имеет 4 типа содержимого.

- Sybase PowerDesigner XML Model Backup
- XACT Sound Bank
- XMLBeans XML Schema Binary (скорее всего мы говорим о таком .xsb)
- Sokoban++ Level Data

В свою очередь с помощью Java мы можем попробовать с ним используя Apache XMLBeans https://xmlbeans.apache.org/

Но нужно помнить, что этими файлами обмениваются гос.органы, у них вероятней всего есть end-to-end шифрование или кастомизация формата. Вам потребуется изучить ваше приложение "Справки БК" (2.5.1) чтобы определить способ шифрования. Или попробовать дешифровать его самостоятельно путем составления словаря символов.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, достаточно поработать с кодировкой:

```
import base64

encoding = 'UTF-32LE'

with open('путь/к/вашему/файлу.xsb', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()[6:]
    data_bytes = data.encode('UTF-8')
    converted = base64.b64decode(data_bytes).decode(encoding)
```